# AngularJS common $destroy for all scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've created an Angular service which serves as a simple mechanism to handle success/warning/error/info alerts to the user in a common place throughout my app (code below).  These alerts are bound to an Angular-UI alert element, listing all the alerts.  My controller handles the plumbing.

So my question is how can I cause every controller in my app to call $alert.clear() upon the controller's destruction?  I believe I can do this the hard way by calling something like this from every single controller:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
  $alerts.clear();
});
```

However, I don't really want that boilerplate stuff sprinkled everywhere.  I'd like to be able to control that behavior common to ALL controllers in my app once and forget about it.

Thanks in advance for any gentle nudge or violent thwack in the right direction!

**HTML snippet**

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

**service.alert.js**

```
app.factory('$alert', function() {

    var alerts = [];

    var clearAlerts = function() {
        alerts = [];
    };

    var closeAlert = function(index, clearOthers) {
        alerts.splice(index, 1);
    };

    var createAlert = function(type, message, clearOthers) {
        if (clearOthers)
            alerts = [];

        alerts.push({type: type, msg: message});
    };

    var alertSuccess = function(message, clearOthers) {
        clearOthers = clearOthers || true;
        createAlert('success', message, clearOthers);
    };

    var alertInfo = function(message, clearOthers) {
        clearOthers = clearOthers || true;
        createAlert('info', message, clearOthers);
    };

    var alertWarning = function(message,clearOthers) {
        clearOthers = clearOthers || true;
        createAlert('warning', message, clearOthers);
    };

    var alertDanger = function(message, clearOthers) {
        clearOthers = clearOthers || true;
        createAlert('danger', message, clearOthers);
    };

    return {
        $alerts: function() { return alerts; },
        $success: function(message, clearOthers) { return alertSuccess(message, clearOthers); },
        $info: function(message, clearOthers) { return alertInfo(message, clearOthers); },
        $warning: function(message, clearOthers) { return alertWarning(message, clearOthers); },
        $danger: function(message, clearOthers) { return alertDanger(message, clearOthers); },
        $clear: function() { return clearAlerts(); },
        $close: function(index) { return closeAlert(index); }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit a controller in all of your controllers.
It still involves you making all your controllers children of a parent controller but other than that it will work flawlessly.

The controller inheritence is done like this:

```
app.controller('ParentCtrl', function ($scope) {
    "use strict";
    $scope.$on("$destroy", function (event, val) {
        alert("Controller Destoryed");
    });
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl', ['$scope', '$controller', function ($scope, $controller) {
    "use strict";
    $controller('ParentCtrl', {$scope: $scope});
}]);
```

Here is a [plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhWVXkpuVJRHB8hdcUEy?p=preview) (notice that a `$destory` event is broadcast on the `$scope` so this example works exactly as if a `$destroy` event was broadcast)

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you!  Even though I have to make the explicit inheritance call, at least I can add common behavior as needed in the future without touching anything but the parent controller.  I really appreciate the help.  You also made it clear to me I need to do some more reading in the AngularJS docs, as I'm not sure it was cemented in my head that controllers were objects with inheritance and all that.

Comment: Glad to have helped :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is may helps you

```
clearAlerts: function() {
        for(var x in this.alerts) {
           delete this.alerts[x];
        }
    }
```

Please take a look at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j46Yh/4/)

Comment: I don't understand why is this better than just initializing a new array.  Could you explain?  Thanks!